# symfony2 http 403 error (access denied) for CSS file localhost?

Tags: javascript, css, image, symfony

I've generated backup of a website has symfony2 CMS

when i extracted it on my localhost its worked fine but (css/js/images) not working

its like the bundles need to rebuild again right ?

i am using Mac os terminal to write symfony2 commands

css tags

```
{% block stylesheets %}
{{ parent() }}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('bundles/cmsfront/css/default.css')}}" type="text/css" />

{% if app.request.attributes.get('_locale') == 'ar' %} 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('bundles/cmsfront/css/rtl.css')}}" type="text/css" />
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

the online website running prefect , i need to move this website to another server so i just want to make a test on my localhost and i got this error for CSS and Images etc

```
403

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /myweb/web/bundles/cmsfront/js/slider.js on this server.
```

any advice ?

Comment: How are you serving this locally? PHP built in server or Apache/Nginx?

Comment: no i am using php/apache MAMP Pro software for mac

Comment: if your live-host is a linux system of some sort, i might have copied the user/group of the live-system to your local system, try change the permissions and owner of the folders

Comment: why is there such as `/myweb/web` in the url ? Your Apache server should be configured to have the `web` folder as the DocumentRoot

Comment: so if i want to moved the website content to another server i have to write the Apache configuration again into the second server ?

Comment: I've moved the website to another server i got this error http://66.7.200.141/~fad1qatardrivers/ , is it because allow_url_open closed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the same error.
I'm using a Mac OS too.

I just restart apache2 with `sudo apachectl restart` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

In my case chmod 775 in terminal helped me

Comment: can you please explain how ? i am new with Symphony

Comment: you can do this-> open terminal -> cd /myweb/web/bundles/cmsfront/js/ then sudo chmod -R 775 ./

Comment: try to chmod 777 in the project root folder

Comment: still same issue :S damn man how to fix this , do i have to rebuild bundles ?

Comment: i think you should manualy check folder and files credentials, i think ls -la would help you, type ls -la in terminal in /myweb/web/bundles/cmsfront/js/ folder